# How to mask environment variables created in Github when running a workflow?

Tags: python, github, environment-variables, github-actions

I created a Github workflow that runs a python script with a cron schedule. On every run of the workflow an access_token is generated, which is required during the next run.

To save the token the python script writes the token to the `GITHUB_ENV` file. In the next step, I use the `hmanzur/actions-set-secret@v2.0.0` action to save the token to a Github secret. All works fine.

My only problem is, that the token gets displayed in the logs of the second step as an environment variable.

Here is a minimal version of the workflow file:

```
name: Tests
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "0 1 * * *"
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python: ['3.9']
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python }}
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt
      - name: Run tests
        working-directory: ./src
        run: python -m unittest
        env:
          ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN}}
      - uses: hmanzur/actions-set-secret@v2.0.0
        with:
          name: 'ACCESS_TOKEN'
          value: ${{env.ACCESS_TOKEN}}
          repository: Me/MyRepository
          token: ${{ secrets.REPO_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
```

I tried applying `::add-mask::`. Adding `echo "ACCESS_TOKEN=::add-mask::$ACCESS_TOKEN" >> $GITHUB_ENV` only added `::add-mask::` to the string.

Is there a way of masking all environment variables in the `GITHUB_ENV` file I can apply in the first step? Can I apply the masking to the variable while writing to the `GITHUB_ENV` file in python? Or is there a way to disable the display of the environment variables during the workflow?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your usage of "::add-mask::" is wrong (not your fault, I hate GHA doc).

What you need to do is:

```
echo "::add-mask::$ACCESS_TOKEN" 
echo "ACCESS_TOKEN=$ACCESS_TOKEN" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

Comment: Thank you @micguo! This makes the whole workflow much cleaner. Updated example repository on [https://github.com/Der-Henning/test-workflows](https://github.com/Der-Henning/test-workflows).

Comment: Thanks.. really helpful.. masking is important :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution, if someone is having the same problem.

There seems to be no direct solution. As a workaround I use the `cryptocode` library to encode and decode the access token in the python script. Only the encrypted token is send to the workflow environment and saved in the repos secret.

Here a minimal working example:

`workflow.yml`:

```
name: Test
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python: ['3.9']
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python }}
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt
      - name: Run tests
        working-directory: ./
        run: python encrypt-secret.py
        env:
          ENCRYPTED_ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{secrets.ENCRYPTED_ACCESS_TOKEN}}
          INITIAL_ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{secrets.INITIAL_ACCESS_TOKEN}}
          PASS_KEY: ${{secrets.REPO_ACCESS_TOKEN}}
      - uses: hmanzur/actions-set-secret@v2.0.0
        with:
          name: 'ENCRYPTED_ACCESS_TOKEN'
          value: ${{env.ENCRYPTED_NEW_ACCESS_TOKEN}}
          repository: Der-Henning/test-workflows
          token: ${{ secrets.REPO_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
```

`encrypt-secret.py`:

```
from os import environ
from random import random
import cryptocode

def main():
  ## Get Github environment file
  ## Only run this part when GITHUB_ENV is set -> workflow detection
  env_file = environ.get('GITHUB_ENV', None)
  if env_file:
    
    ## PASS_KEY to encrypt the secret
    passkey = environ.get("PASS_KEY", None)
    
    access_token = environ.get("INITIAL_ACCESS_TOKEN")

    ## get the encrypted token and decrypt with passkey
    encrypted_old_access_token = environ.get("ENCRYPTED_ACCESS_TOKEN", None)
    if encrypted_old_access_token and passkey: 
      old_access_token = cryptocode.decrypt(encrypted_old_access_token, passkey)
      if old_access_token:
        print("Access Token from secret: {}".format(old_access_token))
        print("Correct Token: {}".format(old_access_token.startswith('ThisIsASecret')))
        access_token = old_access_token
    else:
      print("No encrypted Access Token provided!")

    ######
    #
    # Do stuff here
    # Use old_access_token to access an API ...
    #
    #####
      
    ## Encrypt new access token from API for next run
    ## Save encrypted token to GITHUB_ENV
    new_access_token = "ThisIsASecret{}".format(random())
    print("New Token: {}".format(new_access_token))
    if passkey:
      encrypted_new_access_token = cryptocode.encrypt(new_access_token, passkey)
      with open(env_file, "a") as file:
        file.write("ENCRYPTED_NEW_ACCESS_TOKEN={}\n".format(encrypted_new_access_token))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: Good workaround, but I really hope GH will add support for this natively. Quite a hassle this way... Alternative workaround could be to store the value / var-assignment in a file, and use it from there in the next step by e.g. sourcing that file or similar