# How to mask a environment set in GitHub Workflow

Tags: github, workflow, github-actions

I am using the following to set a env variable:

```yaml
      - name: get root token
        run: |
          echo "ROOT_TOKEN=$(some command | base64 --decode)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

Then I use it in another run within a Python script:

```yaml
      - name: init
        run: |
          python3 scripts/create_entries.py
```

Actually this works great, but the value of `ROOT_TOKEN` is printed in the Workflow console:

```
Run python3 scripts/create_entries.py
  python3 scripts/create_entries.py
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e ***0***
  env:
    DATA: ***
    CONFIG: /home/debian/runner/_work/_temp/config_1646400032032
    ROOT_TOKEN: <this is shown>
```

I tried to mask it using `::add-mask::` like this (but unfortunately that does not work):

```yaml
      - name: get root token
        run: |
          echo "::add-mask::ROOT_TOKEN=$(some command | base64 --decode)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

Does anyone know how to mask the value of `ROOT_TOKEN` in the Workflow console?

Comment: Try running `echo "::add-mask::$ROOT_TOKEN"` in a separate command underneath `echo "ROOT_TOKEN=$(some command | base64 --decode)" >> $GITHUB_ENV`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mask environment variables created in Github when running a workflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70558558/how-to-mask-environment-variables-created-in-github-when-running-a-workflow)

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
echo "::add-mask::$ROOT_TOKEN" 
echo "ROOT_TOKEN=$ROOT_TOKEN" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73041579/17546520