# Key Vault secrets in GitHub Actions workflow

Tags: github, github-actions, azure-keyvault

I have a GitHub Action Workflow wherein I need to access Azure Key Vault secrets and use them. There is the **Azure Key Vault Action** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/github/github-key-vault) that allows you to access the secrets and then use then in the next step, partial code as follows,

```
    - uses: Azure/get-keyvault-secrets@v1
      with: 
        keyvault: "containervault"
        secrets: 'containerPassword, containerUsername'
      id: myGetSecretAction
    - uses: azure/docker-login@v1
      with:
        login-server: myregistry.azurecr.io
        username: ${{ steps.myGetSecretAction.outputs.containerUsername }}
        password: ${{ steps.myGetSecretAction.outputs.containerPassword }}
```

Full YML can be seen in the link above.

However, this action seems to be deprecated in favor of Azure CLI Action (https://github.com/Azure/cli). I could use the action to access the key vault as follows,

```
- name: Azure CLI script
  uses: azure/CLI@v1
  with:
    inlineScript: |
      az keyvault secret show --vault-name MyVaultName --name MySecret --query value
```

However, I am not sure how to pass the value returned by the above to the next step in the workflow. Any assistance here would help.

Thanks in advance
Sushil

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The new recommended way of doing it is covered here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#environment-files

Example:

```
steps:
- name: Azure CLI script
  id: step_one
  uses: azure/CLI@v1
  with:
    inlineScript: |
      echo secret=$(az keyvault secret show --vault-name MyVaultName --name MySecret --query value) >> $GITHUB_ENV
  - name: Use the value
    id: step_two
    run: |
      echo "${{ env.secret }}"
```

Comment: Don't forget to mask the output as listed here https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#example-masking-a-string - full example in this blog post https://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2022-07-14-working-with-add-mask-and-github-actions/

Comment: Adding to the links r.e. masking posted by @fra , this answer may also help https://stackoverflow.com/a/73041579/2667225

Answer (score 0):

I would propose a small improvement to remove double quotes.
Adding `--out tsv` will remove double quotes in the response.

```
steps:
- name: Azure CLI script
  id: step_one
  uses: azure/CLI@v1
  with:
    inlineScript: |
      echo secret=$(az keyvault secret show --vault-name MyVaultName --name MySecret --query value --out tsv) >> $GITHUB_ENV
  - name: Use the value
    id: step_two
    run: |
      echo "${{ env.secret }}"
```